# Fill with @row_number based on group field in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, fields-attributes, unique-id, feature-count

Is there a way to fill the table with a row number so that count will restart as new group (identified by a separate column) starts? As a result, `"row number"` column will restart the count when the new attribute value for a group is found, and will produce row number (1,2,3 etc.) record within this group.

[This post on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11116275/increment-row-number-on-group)  seems to answer my question, but SQL in QGIS does not allow such statements (`DENSE_RANK`) (or it does but I don't know how?).

Comment: Could you mention the QGIS version you used so that it helps others facing similar problems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you need to use a field calculator? If not, the ["Add autoincremental field"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectortable.html#add-autoincremental-field) algorithm from the processing toolbox does what you want including the grouping.

[image: autoincremental]

---

**References:**

- [How to Add Auto Increment Field in QGIS](https://freegistutorial.com/how-to-add-auto-increment-field-in-qgis/)

Comment: I had a similar problem on QGIS version 2.18.16. I needed to auto increment value using Group value as a criteria. I was able to do it using QGIS3.0.3 On the older version QGIS 2.18.16 the group value option is not present.

Answer (score 7):

> Credits to @Gabriel De Luca from his answer
> https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/364575/99589

In the Field Calculator use the following expression:

```
array_find(array_agg($id, "group"), $id) + 1
```

where `"group"` is an attribute that will restart the count when a new group appears.

[image: result]

Answer (score 6):

If you know the row number of the beginning of each group, you can create a group_row_number field in the Field Calculator with a simple `case when` statement.

In my example, I have groups A, B, C and D. Group A is rows 1-4. Group B is rows 5-8. Group C is rows 9-12. Group D is rows 13-17.

Field Calculator expression:
[image]

Result:

[image]

The generalized formula is:

```
case
  when "groupfieldname" = 'first group name' then @row_number
  when "groupfieldname" = 'second group name' then @row_number - [final_row_number_of_first_group]
  when "groupfieldname" = 'third group name' then @row_number - [final_row_number_of_second_group]
  ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks, that works, although I was expecting that there is a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 4):

You can also do this with QGIS 3 field calculator more easy:

```
array_find(array_agg("GROUPFIELDNAME"||'_'||-$id,"GROUPFIELDNAME"),"GROUPFIELDNAME"||'_'||-$id)+1
```

Replace `"GROUPFIELDNAME"` with the name of your field you want to group by.

Comment: can you explain it, please? I used that and it worked. However I can't understand "| |".

Comment: `||` is a concatenator. You could also use `concat(a,b)` instead.