# Adding consecutive unique ID starting from 1 for each distinct set of values

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, sorting, unique-id, feature-count

I need to add a unique `ID` (using `$ID` or `@row_number`) but the problem is that I need to start from 1 to "...n" considering identical values from other field, then, when there is a different value, start counting from 1 again, if the value is repeated, write 2, 3, 4, 5 until finding new distinct values, and so on.

I have an image more explanatory than me, the red column is what I am getting, the green column is how I would like to add the numbers. I guess using the expression `"count_distinct"` could be useful, but I don't know how to structure it with my values.

[image: example]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way of auto\_increment for the ID column in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/132346/is-there-a-way-of-auto-increment-for-the-id-column-in-qgis)

Comment: See the answer "Update for QGIS 3"  by AWGIS

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/132346/is-there-a-way-of-auto-increment-for-the-id-column-in-qgis and this question are different. The answers to the former question don't solve @Geografisica's problem. Please don't vote to close this question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

We can use arrays for that:

```
array_find(
  array_agg(
    $id,
    "ReportID_2"
  ),
  $id
) + 1
```

With `array_agg` we have an array of all *id* grouped by the *ReportID_2* values.

Then, `array_find` gets the position of the current *id* in the previous array, starting with the position 0.

Finally, we add 1 to get the positions from 1.

Comment: Very nice and neet !

Comment: Using $id or @rownumber retrieves values that sometimes are not consecutive, I tried your example but I got increasing numbers like [1, 10, 20, 40], not like [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]. That's why I was asking if the function "count_distinct" could help to obtain increasing and also a consecutive sequence starting from 1.

Comment: @Geografisica, positions in the array are consecutive starting from zero. We are retriving the positions, not the `$id` or `@rownumber`. They are only the identification value to extract its position in the array.

Comment: I used this formula to create a ReportID_3 using ReportID_2:  "ReportID_2"  || '_' || (array_find(
  array_agg(
    $id,
    'ReportID_2'
  ),
  $id
) + 1).

The results are not consecutive yet, I got a sequence that skips values, like ...26, 27 then 29, 45. Still increasing but not consecutive.

Comment: @Geografisica, please, share a test layer in which I can reproduce your behavior, because in my layer I can't reproduce it.

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca Sure, you can access to the shapefile through this link, thank you!: http://www.filedropper.com/moppclaimstestreportid

Comment: @Geografisica, I understand that the difference is minimal and may go unnoticed, but you are not grouping by the value of the field "ReportID_2", but by the literal string 'ReportID_2', which makes all the rows enter the same group. The expression must be: `"ReportID_2" || '_' || (array_find( array_agg( $id, "ReportID_2" ), $id ) + 1)`

Comment: Great Gabriel, I works! now I got the perfect results!, yes, now I understood what was the problem. I really appreciate your help!.

Answer (score 11):

A possible solution employing PyQGIS.

Let's assume there is a point layer called *'Layer_B'* with its attribute table, see image below.

[image: input]

---

### Case 1 without grouping

#### when a new `"id"` has to be assigned in a range of each attribute field

Proceed with `Plugins > Python Console > Show Editor` and paste the script below

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import QVariant

fieldname = "info" #a field which is used as an aggregating factor 
newfieldname = "newid" #a new field that will maintain new ids

layer = iface.activeLayer()
idx = layer.dataProvider().fieldNameIndex(fieldname)

if newfieldname not in layer.fields().names():
    pr = layer.dataProvider()
    pr.addAttributes([QgsField(newfieldname, QVariant.Int)])
    layer.updateFields()

req = QgsFeatureRequest()
req = req.addOrderBy(fieldname)

attr_old = None

with edit(layer):
    for feat in layer.getFeatures(req):
        attr = feat.attributes()[idx]
        if attr == attr_old:
            i += 1
        else:
            i = 1
        feat[newfieldname] = i
        layer.updateFeature(feat)
        attr_old = attr
```

[image: python_console_2]

Press `Run script` [image: run script] and get the output that will look like

[image: result_1]

P.S. Many thanks to @J.Monticolo

---

### Case 2 with grouping

#### when a new `"id"` has to be assigned whenever the value in another attribute field changes

Proceed with `Plugins > Python Console > Show Editor` and paste the script below

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import QVariant

fieldname = "info" #a field which is used as an aggregating factor 
newfieldname = "newid" #a new field that will maintain new ids

layer = iface.activeLayer()
idx = layer.dataProvider().fieldNameIndex(fieldname)

list_attributes = []

for feat in layer.getFeatures():
    list_attributes.append(feat.attributes()[idx])
    
list_attributes = list(set(list_attributes))

dct = {list_attributes[i]: i + 1 for i in range(len(list_attributes))}

if newfieldname not in layer.fields().names():
    pr = layer.dataProvider()
    pr.addAttributes([QgsField(newfieldname, QVariant.Int)])
    layer.updateFields()

with edit(layer):
    for feat in layer.getFeatures():
        attr = feat.attributes()[idx]
        for key, value in dct.items():
            if attr == key:
                feat[newfieldname] = value

        layer.updateFeature(feat)
```

[image: python_console_1]

Press `Run script` [image: run script] and get the output that will look like

[image: result_2]

---

**References:**

- [Free and Open Source GIS Ramblings | PyQGIS 101: Using expressions to compute new field values](https://anitagraser.com/pyqgis-101-introduction-to-qgis-python-programming-for-non-programmers/pyqgis-101-using-expressions-to-compute-new-field-values/)
- [QGIS Python Tutorial: How to Add/Delete Field and Updating Attribute Value](https://www.geodose.com/2018/09/qgis-python-tutorial-add-field-attribute.html)
- [PyQGIS developer cookbook](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/pdf/en/QGIS-testing-PyQGISDeveloperCookbook-en.pdf)
- [How to read the attribute values using PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54057/how-to-read-the-attribute-values-using-pyqgis/138027)

Comment: update your code, here you give the same `newid` for the same `info` value. The author wish a new increment each time the `info` change.

Comment: @Taras I'm very happy to have found this solution, for I can make really good use of the "Case 2" for my work. It would be perfect if there would be a possibillity to sort the numbering of the column "newid" by another field, like "date", so the "earlier" features would get the lower number. Any help would be highly apreciated.

Answer (score 8):

Padding zeros version using PyQGIS:

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()

layer.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField("NEW_FIELD", QVariant.String)])
layer.updateFields()

field = "FIELD"
index = layer.fields().indexFromName(field)
d = {v: 1 for v in layer.uniqueValues(index)}

layer.startEditing()

for feat in layer.getFeatures():
    v = feat[field]
    feat["NEW_FIELD"] = f"{str(d[v]).zfill(2)}" # 2: padding value -> 03, 04
    
    layer.updateFeature(feat)    
    d.update({v: d[v] + 1}) # next value for attibute value
    
layer.commitChanges()
```

Result for `f"{str(d[v]).zfill(2)}"`:

[image]

Result for `f"{v}_{str(d[v]).zfill(2)}"`:

[image]