# Filling column with values at certain condition in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, attribute-table, unique-id

I have blocks of the road network and these blocks are divided every 200m.

I want to name them based on the ID_Sufix number. For example, if the stretch road ID is 10001 and this contains 26 small blocks, I want to 10001_1,1001_2.....10001_26. So like this for every set of blocks, it needed to be done. How can I achieve it?

[image]

Comment: Do you have any scripting experience? Calculating a field is fairly easy but naming sections from start to end is *way* more difficult and would require some scripting.

Comment: Are they already sorted by start to end?

Comment: Maybe this thread [Adding consecutive unique ID starting from 1 for each distinct set of values](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/364563/adding-consecutive-unique-id-starting-from-1-for-each-distinct-set-of-values) can help you. Use additionally `"ID" || `.