# Adding unique ID for consecutive groups using Field calculator in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, expression, grouping, unique-id

I found a [similar question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/373899) on this site and the answer suggested:

```
array_find(
    array_distinct(
        array_agg("PortCluster_ID")
        ),
        "PortCluster_ID"
    ) + 1
```

but using this expression gives me the following result (group1)

[image]

What I want to do is have what I wrote in white color on the attached image. As you can see I have consecutive `"PortCluster_ID"`s ordered in time, and i have a group of 119, then a group of 111 and then a group of 119 again, for this second group of 119 I want to have a new `"ID"`.

What this data represents is fishing trips in and out of ports, some trips end in the same port (same `"PortCluster_ID"`) but are obviously a different trip (ordered in ascending time).

Comment: Could you perhaps look at a way of classifying the data (refining it) by the Timestamp, and then use the methodology you have now to create the grouping? I am not sure what the timestamps are, and what constitutes a "trip" but refining the data a little may allow for your current method to work.

Comment: Couldn't I use the same expression stated in my question but conditioned upon @row_number? So for example, this new expression or python code would see that it is again 119 and it would "want to group it to the same group as the first 119 group" but because in the previous row the PortCluster_ID was different,111, it would group this set of 119s to group 3. So i would have to modify my statement in such a way that it would check the previous row as well? But I do not know how to do that.

Comment: @MrXsquared do you have a suggested answer?

Comment: Did you also try the ["Add autoincremental field"](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectortable.html#add-autoincremental-field)?

Comment: @Taras how to realize this specific task with `Add autoincremental field`? The tricky part is to group fields, partially based on `PortCluster_ID`, partly on `GpsTime`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

create an ID field following the `GpsTime` field, then create the `group1` field and populate it with the following expression (can be improved):

```
with_variable('cucu',
   aggregate( 
   layer:=@layer_name,
   aggregate:='array_agg',
   expression:=
   (array_find(array_agg("ID", "PortCluster_ID"),"ID"))-"ID"),
with_variable('cucu2',
   (array_find(array_agg("ID", "PortCluster_ID"),"ID"))-"ID",
   array_find(array_distinct(@cucu),@cucu2)+1))
```

[image]

the scheme used:

[image]

sample data:
https://gist.github.com/pigreco/48cf061c183809b0e69628a13493f771

Comment: Works! And easier than my solution.

Comment: Which software did you use to create this awesome screenshot?

Comment: https://www.screenpresso.com/

Comment: Works! Thank you!

Comment: if that's ok for you, please mark it as an answer

Answer (score 3):

### The basic idea

You want to create groups, based on an attribute value, but to assign different group-ids to the same values based on an order value (time) of another field.

1. To use this order, it's easier to first convert the datetime field to an integer `id` field.
2. The basic idea now is to check for each feature if the next feature in the defined order has the same value or not. If it has **not** the same value, it is the last feature of the group, the `top` feature. Assign a value to it - easiest one just take its `id` value.
3. In a next step, assign the same `id` value to all other features of the same group if they are **before** this "top" feature, based on the order.
4. Finally, convert the non consecutive group `id` values to consecutive numbers, starting with 1.

### How to implement it

To do so, use QGIS expressions and create four new attribute fields, one for each of the steps described above, using [Field calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#using-the-field-calculator).

1. Create a new field called `id` that represents the order number based on your GPSTime field. Use this expression: `array_find (array_sort (array_agg( "GPStime")), "GPStime")+1`
2. Create a new field called `top`. It creates an entry, based on the `id` of the feature, for the last element (feature) of the groups you want: the highest / last element before the next group starts. Use this expression:

   ```
    array_get (
        array_foreach (
            generate_series (0,array_length ( array_agg ( "PortCluster_ID" ))),
            if (
                array_get (
                    array_agg("PortCluster_ID"),
                    @element
                ) = 
                array_get (
                    array_agg ("PortCluster_ID"),
                    @element+1
                ) = 0 or id = array_max (array_agg( id)),
                @element+1,
                ''
            )
        )
        ,id-1
    )
   ```
3. Create a new field `group` that assigns the value of the groups last feature (created in step 2) to all other features of the same group. Use this expression:

   ```
    if (
        top is NULL, 
        array_min (
            array_filter( 
                array_sort ( 
                    array_agg (top, filter:=top >0)
                ),
                @element > id-1
            )
        ),
        top
    )
   ```
4. Now create another field `count` that converts the group-values to incrementing numbers starting with 1. Use this expression:

   ```
    array_first (
        array_foreach (
            array_distinct (
                array_agg (group)
            ),
            array_find (
                array_distinct (
                    array_agg (group)
                ), 
                group
            )
        )
    )+1
   ```

*See the results for each step in the corresponding attribute fields. The last column returns the values you're looking for, groups are highlighted in blue/orange:*
[image]