# QGIS field calculator: grouping incremental values per category

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I have a shapefile with a categorical field (cat) and an integer field (value) in QGIS.

I want to create a new field (group), that groups incremental values per category until there is a break/gap into a new 'group' field. The group field needs to a unique integer per group - this field does not need to be incremental.

Below is an example of what I am after, I would need to generate the 'group' field as follows:

| cat | value | group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 4 | 2 |
| 1 | 5 | 2 |
| 2 | 0 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 3 | 4 |

is there a way to do this using field calculator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this using a virtual layer

Go to the menu `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...` and enter the following query and adjust for your layer name.

```sql
SELECT *, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN group_break THEN 1 END) 
         OVER (ORDER BY cat,val) AS group_id
FROM (
SELECT *,
    COALESCE(
     (val-1 = LAG(val) 
        OVER (PARTITION BY cat ORDER BY val))
    ,FALSE) IS FALSE AS group_break
FROM myLayer) sub;
```

Let's break it down: First, in the `sub` subquery, we identify rows that should get a new group id. Do do this, we break the table by `cat` value, then order it by `val` and if the previous (`lag()`) value is null (i.e it was for a different `cat`) OR not equal to the current value -1, then we know it is the 1st of a new group.

Then, in the outer query, we compute a running sum, with a value of 1 for rows corresponding to new groups, and 0 otherwise. Because we order again by `cat` and `val`, the running total becomes the new `group_id` you are looking for.

---

Using the input you have provided, here it what is generated:

[image]

Comment: Nice use of Virtual Layers!  For future reference, The input layer's name (you used *myLayer*) must match the name used in the QGIS table of contents, and that name cannot contain any spaces.

Comment: Thank you, this answer solved my question. My data was too big to run efficiently with virtual layers so I adapted this code using Pgadmin4 instead.

Answer (score 2):

Use this expression with Field Calculator:

```
with_variable(
    'arr',
    array_agg (
        if (
            cat = attribute (get_feature_by_id (@layer, $id+1), 'cat') and 
            value + 1 = attribute (get_feature_by_id (@layer, $id+1), 'value'),
            0,
            $id
        )
    ),
    array_find (
        array_filter (@arr, @element >0),
        array_filter (@arr, @element >= $id)[0]
    )
)+1
```

The expression is [based on the one explained here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/418688/88814), but does it in one step.

[image]

Comment: This code will work on pre-sorted data, but it will generate unexpected results if the data isn't sorted.