# Numbering row based on date field in QGIS

Tags: qgis, expression, date, array, order

In QGIS 3.28 I just want to create a row number (Column `"Número"`) based on the date of the column on the left (`"Fecha"`), I'm sure it's pretty easy but I'm completely new.

`@row_number` doesn't work at all because the order is different.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this expression in [Field Calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#using-the-field-calculator):

```
array_find(
    array_agg($id, order_by:="Fecha"), 
    $id
    ) + 1
```

[image]

Comment: Did it before already > https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/364619/99589